# dplyr::mutate: temporary expensive variable as input to several other operations, rowwise

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

It is a little tricky to show my problem with real data but I hope the following explains:

```
data_frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4)) %>% 
rowwise %>% 
mutate(c = a*b, d = c-1, e=c+2) %>% 
ungroup
```

In the above example of course the `rowwise` is not needed.

Now lets suppose that the calculation to make `c` is both time consuming,  `c` is a large object and not vectorized.
So you don't want to have to execute it twice and you want it to be cleared from the memory after each row calculation happens.

Is there a clever way to do this? Perhaps with `purrr::map`?

Comment: Someone, please correct me if I am wrong but objects are not vectorized; it is operations that are vectorized. In this case, multiplication, addition and subtraction are all vectorized for the vectors `a` and `b`. And hence, for `c`. If what I am saying is completely off, then I may not have understood the question.

Comment: Yes I meant that calculations/operations to create c, d, e should be assumed not to be vectorized for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer using `purrr`s `invoke_rows`.

```
library(purrr)

MyDf<-data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4))
invoke_rows(.d=MyDf, .f=function(a,b){c=a*b
c(d=c-1,
e=c+2)},
.collate="cols")
```

**Update**

In response to the comment of @JanStanstrup, if you have another column that you want as part of the output but does not appear in the calculation, you can do this:

```
MyDf<-data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4), dummy=c(6,7))
invoke_rows(.d=MyDf, .f=function(a,b,...){c=a*b
c(d=c-1,
  e=c+2)},
.collate="cols")
```

Here, `dummy` and any other columns are passed via the `...` as  an argument to the `.f` function, but are not used in that function, so they just gets passed on along.

Comment: Fantastic! That works. I noticed that it seems it errors out if .d contains columns not referenced in .f. --> `MyDf<-data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4), dummy = c(6,7))` --> ` unused argument (dummy = .d[[c(3, i)]])`. Any fix for that? I can of course join the result with the original data.frame but that seems inelegant.

Comment: I saw what you did with adding the unused column to the function. While this works it could be a bit messy if you have many columns. Also it is more difficult to maintain if you add new columns. Perhaps there is a way to extract the column names in a way that all of them can be input to the function?

Comment: Alternatively I guess you could just include one column that is unique such that you can join with your original table.

Comment: You certainly could. I just edited my answer to add `...` to the function call instead of specific column names, which I think is much nicer if you have a whole bunch of additional columns.

Comment: Oh cool. Yes the "..." is definitely the right solutions. Thanks again!

Comment: Any way to make this run in parallel? I tried with multidplyr::partition but invoke_rows doesn't accept a party_df.

Comment: @JanStanstrup I haven't worked much with parallel - you should probably ask this as a new question.